# Play Framework 2.4.x - activator ~run does not substitute env vars in application.conf

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm running my Play application on heroku. On heroku the idea is to set various settings through env variables. For example AWS S3 secret access key and its ID. That's understandable. So following good practices I put the following settings to my conf/application.conf:

```
# AWS.
# ~~~~~
aws.accessKeyID = ${?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
aws.secretAccessKey = ${?AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

Ok, all good. Now whenever I run in PROD or DEV mode I can change those and not be worried about hard-coding them. The problem is though that when I run activator ~run to develop my app locally these settings are not being read and set. It's like activator ~run ignores completely substituting options for env variables. I read and print them in the following way when loading my index page:

```
import play.api.Play.current
...
val v1 = current.configuration.getString("aws.accessKeyID")
val v2 = current.configuration.getString("aws.secretAccessKey")
println("v1=" + v1 + ", v2=" + v2)
```

Let me give even more details as to what's happening:

```
floyd@floyd-VirtualBox:~/myproj$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
access-key-id
floyd@floyd-VirtualBox:~/myproj$ echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
secret-access-key
floyd@floyd-VirtualBox:~/myproj$ activator ~run
[info] Loading project definition from /home/floyd/myproj/project
[info] Set current project to myproj (in build file:/home/floyd/myproj/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/floyd/myproj/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Compiled in 15s
[info] - play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] - application - ReactiveMongoApi starting...
[info] - application - ReactiveMongoApi successfully started with DB 'test'! Servers:
        [localhost:27017]
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
v1=None, v2=None
```

Both cases None is printed and I would expect to see the value that was stored in the env variables.

Thanks upfront for your help!

Comment: I've tested this on 2.4.x. Works as you expect. Where are you calling `println("v1=" + v1 + ", v2=" + v2)` from? Also can you try 'activator -D AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access-key-id ~run

Comment: I call it on my getIndexPage function of my ApplicationController. The thing is I don't want to use -D since AFAIK those env variables should be read from the environment automatically. I don't want to pass them again and mention them yet in another place. So it works for you even without -D usage? Hmmm, I'll retest later today. What activator version do you use? Thanks.

Comment: I was only suggesting the -D's to try and isolate the problem. Tested with activator 1.3.5 running via git-bash on windows and 1.3.6 on Mac. I've also used the same technique in Play! 2.3.x. Double check you can println some other custom config that isn't relying on an env var

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work for me, I need to explicitly use -D's. I came up with a workaround for now I've posted as an answer below. Thanks for help though. My activator version is the same BTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer might be in how you set your Environment variable. To simulate your experience

With a application.conf of

`foo.bar=${?FOO}`

Then

```
$ FOO=BAR
$ activator ~run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pw/dev/play-project/project
[info] Set current project to play-project (in build file:/Users/pw/dev/play-project/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[success] Compiled in 687ms
[info] - application - Application is started!!! ****
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
v1=None
```

crucially if you export your environment variable like in the following snippet, the intended behaviour is achieved

```
$ unset FOO
$ echo $FOO

$ export FOO=ASDF
$ activator ~run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pw/dev/play-project/project
[info] Set current project to play-project (in build file:/Users/pw/dev/play-project/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[success] Compiled in 1s
[info] - application - Application is started!!! ****
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
v1=Some(ASDF)
```

Comment: You're totally right! Ehh, I had a file dev-env with VAR1=a and I was doing, source dev-env, before running activator ~run, but that makes it available just for the current shell, it doesn't put VAR1 in the environment. That means I get 'a' when I do echo $VAR1, but env | grep VAR1 shows nothing. What I need to have in my file, if I want to source it before ~run is export VAR1. Thanks. Ehh, stupid simple bug ;)

Comment: interestingly it does not seem to work on Windows. whether I use a System environment variable or not, can't seem to get it to work with activator run. Ended up using the -D option. (BTW Found -D option seems to need to _precede_ the run command.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions (or rather workarounds...) I came up with is the following, I've created a dev-env file with the content:

```
-DVAR1=a \
-DVAR2=b \
-DVAR3=c
```

and a run-dev executable script with content:

```
activator ~run `cat dev-env`
```

This allowed me to have separate dev settings while not hard-coding anything inside conf/application.conf.

Unfortunately I can't make activator ~run to read the env variables without explicitly passing them to the activator (under the hood these are passed to jvm).